# Access filesystem from Node app in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, filesystems

I'm having some issues trying to access the filesystem inside a docker container; I keep getting this issue:

```
fs.access(path, fs.R_OK & fs.W_OK, function (err) {
       ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'access'
```

What I want to do is to check access in the file system before I create a file in it.

The path and error is generated from the following code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var rootPath = path.dirname(require.main.filename);
fs.access(rootPath, fs.R_OK & fs.W_OK, callback);
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
docker exec -it [name of container] bash
```

then:

```
node --version
```

And make sure that the node you're running is the same as the one outside of docker. In my case the

```
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
```

I used to  install node in docker fetched me docker `v0.10.25` which doesn't support the `fs` module I used.

I fixed it by adding the following two commands to my Dockerfile:

```
RUN curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -
RUN sudo apt-get install --yes nodejs
```

**NOTE:**
My fix is for ubuntu docker images.